# Can't resolve another web API by using its public domain

Tags: c#, azure

I have two WebApi apps up and running on Azure, first one is a generic oauth server and the second one is a webapi server.

- The oauth server has public domain **xxx.yyy.com** (and **xxx-yyy.azurewebsites.net** given from Azure by default)
- The WebApi server has public domain **zzz.yyy.com** (and **zzz-yyy.azurewebsites.net** given from Azure by default)

When WebApi server tries to resolve oauth server by public domain, it fails (a WebException is thrown with message **The remote name could not be resolved: xxx.yyy.com**), when WebApi server tries by Azure's domain it works.

Comment: Can you access the oauth server using a browser or Postman using the domain?

Comment: Try something like https://digwebinterface.com/ and see what you get. Sounds like a DNS problem.

Comment: @CSharpRocks Through Postman all works

Comment: @juunas DNS are ok, in my localhost I use public domains

Comment: Hmm, could just be taking time to propagate through to other DNS servers

Comment: @juunas I've setup dns some days ago, _digwebinterface_ shows same result to all dns providers. I think there is some restriction in Azure

Comment: No, by default there should be no restriction. You are running on *regular* App Service and not an App Service Environment / Isolated tier, right?

Comment: Yes, app service